# How to create an array for JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, json

From PHP code I want to create an json array:

```
[
  {"region":"valore","price":"valore2"},
  {"region":"valore","price":"valore2"},
  {"region":"valore","price":"valore2"}
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate .json file with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467945/how-to-generate-json-file-with-php)

Comment: Same question back in 2009: [Generate json string from multidimensional array data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1435072/2943403)

Answer (score 172):

Easy peasy lemon squeezy: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

There's a post by `andyrusterholz at g-m-a-i-l dot c-o-m` on the aforementioned page that can also handle complex nested arrays (if that's your thing).

Answer (score 137):

Use PHP's native [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), like this:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array(
        "region" => "valore",
        "price" => "valore2"
    ),
    array(
        "region" => "valore",
        "price" => "valore2"
    ),
    array(
        "region" => "valore",
        "price" => "valore2"
    )
);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

---

**Update**: To answer your question in the comment. You do it like this:

```
$named_array = array(
    "nome_array" => array(
        array(
            "foo" => "bar"
        ),
        array(
            "foo" => "baz"
        )
    )
);
echo json_encode($named_array);
```

Comment: Excuse me but if I want {"nome_array": [{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"baz"}]} ??

Answer (score 49):

Simple: Just create a (nested) PHP array and call `json_encode` on it. Numeric arrays translate into JSON lists (`[]`), associative arrays and PHP objects translate into objects (`{}`). Example:

```
$a = array(
        array('foo' => 'bar'),
        array('foo' => 'baz'));
$json = json_encode($a);
```

Gives you:

```
[{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"baz"}]
```

Comment: Excuse me but if I want {"nome_array": [{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"baz"}]} ??

Comment: Read my post again. If you want something to translate into a JSON object, make it an associative array in PHP (where the keys are strings). If you want it to translate into a JSON list, make it a plain array (with implicit integer keys). The value of each array element can in turn be an array, which is what you want.

Comment: Also, array indices need to start on 0. If they are 1-based, they get converted to k-v objects.

Answer (score 16):

Best way that you should go every time for creating json in php is to first convert values in ASSOCIATIVE array.

After that just simply encode using `json_encode($associativeArray)`. I think it is the best way to create json in php because whenever we are fetching result form sql query in php most of the time we got values using `fetch_assoc` function, which also return one associative array.

```
$associativeArray = array();
$associativeArray ['FirstValue'] = 'FirstValue';
```

...
etc.

After that.

```
json_encode($associativeArray);
```

Answer (score 9):

also for array you can use short annotattion:

```
$arr = [
    [
        "region" => "valore",
        "price" => "valore2"
    ],
    [
        "region" => "valore",
        "price" => "valore2"
    ],
    [
        "region" => "valore",
        "price" => "valore2"
    ]
];

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Shame I had to scroll so far for this..

Answer (score 4):

That's how I am able to do with the help of solution given by @tdammers below. 
The following line will be placed inside foreach loop.

```
$array[] = array('power' => trim("Some value"), 'time' => "time here" );
```

And then encode the array with json encode function

```
json_encode(array('newvalue'=> $array), 200)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just typing this single line would give you a json array ,

`echo json_encode($array);`

Normally you use `json_encode` to read data from an ios or android app. so make sure you do not echo anything else other than the accurate json array.

Answer (score 1):

I created a crude and simple jsonOBJ class to use for my code. PHP does not include json functions like JavaScript/Node do. You have to iterate differently, but may be helpful.

```
<?php

// define a JSON Object class
class jsonOBJ {
    private $_arr;
    private $_arrName;

    function __construct($arrName){
        $this->_arrName = $arrName;
        $this->_arr[$this->_arrName] = array();

    }

    function toArray(){return $this->_arr;}
    function toString(){return json_encode($this->_arr);}

    function push($newObjectElement){
        $this->_arr[$this->_arrName][] = $newObjectElement; // array[$key]=$val;
    }

    function add($key,$val){
        $this->_arr[$this->_arrName][] = array($key=>$val);
    }
}

// create an instance of the object
$jsonObj = new jsonOBJ("locations");

// add items using one of two methods
$jsonObj->push(json_decode("{\"location\":\"TestLoc1\"}",true)); // from a JSON String
$jsonObj->push(json_decode("{\"location\":\"TestLoc2\"}",true));

$jsonObj->add("location","TestLoc3"); // from key:val pairs

echo "<pre>" . print_r($jsonObj->toArray(),1) . "</pre>";
echo "<br />" . $jsonObj->toString();
?>
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [locations] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [location] => TestLoc1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [location] => TestLoc2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [location] => TestLoc3
                )

        )

)


{"locations":[{"location":"TestLoc1"},{"location":"TestLoc2"},{"location":"TestLoc3"}]}
```

To iterate, convert to a normal object:

```
$myObj = $jsonObj->toArray();
```

Then:

```
foreach($myObj["locations"] as $locationObj){
    echo $locationObj["location"] ."<br />";
}
```

Outputs:

TestLoc1
 TestLoc2
 TestLoc3

Access direct:

```
$location = $myObj["locations"][0]["location"];
$location = $myObj["locations"][1]["location"];
```

A practical example:

```
// return a JSON Object (jsonOBJ) from the rows
    function ParseRowsAsJSONObject($arrName, $rowRS){
        $jsonArr = new jsonOBJ($arrName); // name of the json array

        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($rowRS);
        if($rows > 0){
            while($rows > 0){
                $rd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowRS);
                $jsonArr->push($rd);
                $rows--;
            }
            mysqli_free_result($rowRS);
        }
        return $jsonArr->toArray();
    }
```