# How to convert array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP : Create array for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739871/php-create-array-for-json)

I have an array like this :

```
Array ( [0] => tag1 [1] => tag2 [2] => tags17c [3] => tags20 [4] => tags21)
```

I want put that array on javascript, and the format must be like this :

```
var Tag = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tags17c', 'tags20', 'tags21'];
```

How to convert it?
please, help me out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to use json for that, as Charly suggested, using json_encode. Though there is no real reason for using array_values() as far as I know,

```
var Tag = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

Comment: If the array is an associative array, then a JSON object will be created.

Answer (score 6):

```
var Tag = <?php echo json_encode(array_map("htmlspecialchars", $your_array)); ?>;
```