# JSON Encoding Multiple Query returns in PHP for iOS

Tags: php, ios, json

I followed Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on creating a web service / hooking it up to iOS but his example the returned results only have one possible row returned in the query. I'd like to return all possible results in a JSON format but I am confused how to store them as the correct key.

Here's what I have for the PHP:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT userID, lat, lng FROM Connections WHERE airline=? AND flight_number=? ');
$stmt->bind_param("si", $airline, $flight_number);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($otherUser, $otherLat, $otherLng);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        break;
    }
 $stmt->close();

if ($otherUser) {
        //sendResponse(403, 'Code already used');
        //return false;
        $myLatLng = "$lat,$long";
        $otherLatLng="$otherLat,$otherLng";
        $results = getDistanceBetween($myLatLng,$otherLatLng);
        $miles = $results[0];
        $minutes = $results[1];
        $result = array(
                "other_user" => $otherUser,
                "distance" => $miles,
                "duration" => $minutes,

                );
        sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
        return true;
    }
```

On the Obj-C side of things I get these values using this code:

```
 if (request.responseStatusCode == 200) {
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSString *otherUser = [responseDict objectForKey:@"other_user"];
    NSString *otherDistance = [responseDict objectForKey:@"distance"];
    NSString *otherDuration = [responseDict objectForKey:@"duration"];
```

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP code you want to create a nested array and then use json_encode().  Here is a previous question with more detail about the PHP side of your problem: [How to create an array for JSON using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739871/php-create-array-for-json)

On the iOS side, since your webservice will return a JSON response representing multiple items, calling `JSONValue` on the response string will return an `NSArray` object instead of an `NSDictionary`.  You can then iterate over the items in the array (which will themselves be NSDictionary items) and pull out the values you need.

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSArray *responseArray = [responseString JSONValue];

for (NSDictionary* item in responseArray) {
    NSString *otherUser = [item objectForKey:@"other_user"];
    NSString *otherDistance = [item objectForKey:@"distance"];
    NSString *otherDuration = [item objectForKey:@"duration"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but do you know how I can return the array in JSON format? I'm confused with the PHP/SQL/JSON part but I didn't even consider the iOS Array part