# String format - Logic issue

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP : Create array for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739871/php-create-array-for-json)

I need to output data in the following JSON format.

Output :

```
[
    {
        "name": "jake",
        "age": "20"

}
]
```

In the following code, i need to set the key and value pairs in a way where it will give the above JSON output. How could i do this ?

Code :

```
$result = array();
$key = array("name", "age");
$value = array("jake", "20");

while($i>2)
{
    $result [] = HERE I NEED TO SET <key : value> COMBINATION, I NEED IT TO SET IN A WAY IT WILL GIVE THE FORMAT OF THE JSON OUTPUT GIVEN ABOVE.
}


echo json_encode($result );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$key = array("name", "age");
$value = array("jake", "20");
$json=array();
for($i=0;$i<=count($key)-1;$i++)
{
    $json[$key[$i]]=$value[$i];
}
echo json_encode($json); // {"name":"jake","age":"20"}
```

Comment: Micro-optimization: `$count = count($key); for($i=0;$i<$count;++$i){}`

Comment: Only for 2 items, I thought it's not necessary, but it's a good practice and thanks. :-)

Comment: @hsz: Or just `for($i=0,$count=count($key);$i<$count;++$i){}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
$result = array_combine($key, $value);
```

Results:

```
var_dump($result);

array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "jake"
  ["age"]=>
  string(2) "20"
}

var_dump(json_encode($result));

string(26) "{"name":"jake","age":"20"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [array_combile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

```
$result = array();
$key = array("name", "age");
$value = array("jake", "20");

$result[] = array_combine($key, $value);

echo json_encode($result);
```