# Extjs - Combobox with data from php file not working

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a combobox and i want to get data from php server

Here is my Index.html code **http://jsfiddle.net/UQcgA/**

Here is my data.php file. 

 But when i click to combo then nothing show :(. How can i fix that thanks

```
<?php
// function to create json
function GetCategories() {
    $categories = "{'rows':[";
    $categories = "{'id':'1', 'name':'Category 1'},";
    $categories .= "{'id':'2', 'name':'Category 2'},";
    $categories .= "{'id':'3', 'name':'Category 3'}";
    $categories .= "]}";
    return $categories;
}
echo GetCategories(); // sent to client
?>
```

Comment: What does the returned JSON string look like?

Comment: @existdissolve it look {'id':'1', 'name':'Category 1'},{'id':'2', 'name':'Category 2'},{'id':'3', 'name':'Category 3'}]}

Comment: it needs to look like: {'rows':[{'id':'1', 'name':'Category 1'},{'id':'2', 'name':'Category 2'},{'id':'3', 'name':'Category 3'}]}. You are missing a concatenation in your code. But Musa suggested, you really shouldn't build JSON by hand, if you can help it.

Comment: @existdissolve I using echo "{'rows':[{'id':'1', 'name':'Category 1'},{'id':'2', 'name':'Category 2'},{'id':'3', 'name':'Category 3'}]}"; But it's not working :(

Comment: What is returned when you view the request in developer tools or Fire bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is with your store definition. You are using the definition for ExtJS 3. This is a correct way to define store in ExtJS 4.1:

```
        var values = new Ext.data.Store({
            fields: [
                {name: 'id', type: 'integer'},
                {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
            ],
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                url: 'data.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'rows'
                }
            }),
            autoLoad: true
        });
```

You have a problem with your `json data` too (you're missing a period in the 2nd line also). This will work:

```
// function to create json
function GetCategories() {
    $categories = '{"rows": [';
    $categories .= '{"id": "1", "name": "Category 1"},';
    $categories .= '{"id": "2", "name": "Category 2"},';
    $categories .= '{"id": "3", "name": "Category 3"}';
    $categories .= "]}";
    return $categories;
}
echo GetCategories(); // sent to client
?>
```

**NOTE:** it is always a best practice to build the JSON string using `json_encode` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6739890/1195379).

Comment: I found define at http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Ext-JS/UseJsonReaderastheStorereader.htm that false? :(

Comment: Are you sure it is for ExtJS 4.1?

Comment: Code in the link you posted has this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-3.0.0/ext-all.js"></script>` which means it is for ExtJS 3! It won't work with 4.1