# JSON not working in javascript ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

please your help, i have problem in my ajax request. i have return text data and i want to convert it to JSON using json_parse but it does't work

the data that return from the ajax request looks like this :

```
data = "{"name":"ehab","mobile":"xxx"}{"name":"Hamza","mobile":"zzzz"}"
```

i want to convert this data to json i use the following ajax request

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getGroup.php",
                data: { "searchText" : number},
                 success: function(data)
                {
                data = JSON.parse(data);

                debugger;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                 debugger;
              }
```

if i use this way error message returns

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

my php array file

```
$sql ="select * from recipients where `groupid`='$searchText'";

        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
        $data='';
        if(mysql_num_rows($res)> 0) 
                    {
                    for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($res);$i++) {
                    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);


                    $output =  array('name'=>$row['rec_name'],
                 'mobile'=>$row['mobile_number']);

                    echo json_encode($output);
                    }
```

please advice

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ check your json format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON is invalid

```
{"name":"ehab","mobile":"xxx"}{"name":"Hamza","mobile":"zzzz"}
Here -------------------------^
```

You cannot have two objects at the top level like that.

You could make it an array by wrapping it in `[...]` and separating the entries with `,`:

```
[{"name":"ehab","mobile":"xxx"},{"name":"Hamza","mobile":"zzzz"}]
```

Then you'd access it like this:

```
console.log(data[0].name); // "ehab"
console.log(data[1].name); // "Hamza"
```

Or using a loop, `forEach`, etc.

---

Side note: If your server returns correctly-identified, valid JSON, jQuery will parse it for you before calling your `success` function, so no need for the `JSON.parse` in your code.

Comment: could you please help me how to write the JSON array ?


$sql ="select * from recipients where `groupid`='$searchText'";

  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
  $data='';
  if(mysql_num_rows($res)> 0) 
     {
     for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($res);$i++) {
     $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
     
     
     $output =  array('name'=>$row['rec_name'],
                 'mobile'=>$row['mobile_number']);
              
     echo json_encode($output);
     }

Comment: i add the php code in the question please your help to write the json array in correct way

Comment: Create an array. Add a new object each time you go around the loop. Convert *only* the *final result* to JSON.

Comment: @Haifaaaa: That would be a **new** question. But it's [already been asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739871/php-create-array-for-json), just search for "Create JSON PHP".