# Creating a JavaScript array from PHP – square brackets and curly braces

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am trying to pass code from my PHP backend to the google-chart JavaScript API. I have had success using PHP’s `json_encode()`, for passing arrays of numbers and strings. 
For simple data arrays `json_encode()` works just fine:

```php
<?php $data = [['Series1', 'Series2'], [0, 1], [2, 3], [3, 4]]; />
```

```php
<script>
var data = <?php echo(json_encode($data));?>;
</script>
```

But, the [Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#stacked-bar-charts) requires that row-parameters be passed as objects in {curly braces}.

Here is the JavaScript array I am trying to produce:

```
var data = [
    ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
     'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
    ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
    ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
];
```

The trouble is producing the `{role: 'annotation'}` bit in PHP. Any suggestions?

Comment: You do not `JSON.parse()` JSON text when it is outputted directly in `<script>` tags. Actually doing so will throw an error

Comment: Oh, you're right. I don't have that in there. I was going from memory and forgot that I didn't need that bit. I edited the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP : Create array for JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739871/php-create-array-for-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$data = [['Series1', 'Series2', ['role'=>'annotation']], [0, 1], [2, 3], [3, 4]];
```

You can create objects in php by creating a new `stdClass`, but an dictionary (key => value array) is converted to JSON the same way (with curly brackets). This would work as well:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->role = 'annotation';

$data = [['Series1', 'Series2', $object], [0, 1], [2, 3], [3, 4]];
```

Comment: That seems to have worked! I thought I tried that earlier, but must have made a mistake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice! If it worked, it's good practice to mark the answer as correct (by hitting the green checkmark next to the counter)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object in PHP and json_encode will create an object from that:

```
$myObj = new stdClass;
$myObj->role = "annotation";
```

Then 'json_encode($myObj);' will return the JSON object you want.