# how to Create Json in Php

Tags: php, json

How to Create Json Like This In Php?

```
[
 [
  "16226281",
   "11",
   "Disclosure.1994.720p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG",
   "finished"
  ],
  [ 
   "16226038",
   "140",
   "Courage The Cowardly Dog (1999-2002)",
   "finished"
  ],
  [
   "16226020",
   "101",
   "[R.G. Mechanics] Call of Duty 4 Modern Warfare",
   "finished"
  ]
]
```

I search a lot on the internet but couldn't get any result.

Comment: yes sir Array to json in php

Comment: if you actually **did** do any research at all, you definitely **aren't good** at it: see also **[the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**

Comment: @AirBuddy use json_encode();

Comment: Don't see any efforts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an array for JSON using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739871/how-to-create-an-array-for-json-using-php)

Comment: 1) What you put in the question is not json, just an array. 2)To get json simply stick that array in to json_encode() finction.

Comment: exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545406/how-to-make-json-in-php

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = [
 [
  "16226281",
   "11",
   "Disclosure.1994.720p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG",
   "finished"
],
[ 
  "16226038",
  "140",
  "Courage The Cowardly Dog (1999-2002)",
  "finished"
 ],
 [
  "16226020",
  "101",
  "[R.G. Mechanics] Call of Duty 4 Modern Warfare",
  "finished"
 ]
]


echo json_encode($arr);
```

Follow below link :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Just create an array

```
<?php
   $arr = array(
       array(
         "16226281",
         "11",
         "Disclosure.1994.720p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG",
         "finished"
       ),
       # ....
     );
```

and for output  as json

```
 <?php echo json_encode($arr);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of JSON encoding using the inbuilt json_encode PHP function which can create JSON formatted data from PHP array:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
'key 1' => "value 1",
'key 2' => "value 2",
'key 3' => "value 3"
);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Source: [How to create JSON formatted text in PHP](https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-create-json-formatted-text-in-php/)