# com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

Tags: java, android, json

I have a json list like this from PHP:

```
$Json = '[{"test":"1", "message":"try it"}, 
{"test":"2", "message":"try it"}, {"test":"3", "message":"try it"} ...]';
$final = [ 'error' => '1', 'json' => json_encode($Json)];
die(json_encode($final));
```

From Android i can show the result like this:

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject res = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
Log.w("Return", response.body().toString());
```

All works fine until now, but when i try to make a new `Json Object` from the returned results, i get this error message:

```
com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject
```

Here what i did:

```
JsonObject json = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(new Gson().toJson(res.get("json").toString()));
Log.w("JSON", json.toString());
```

Any fix please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, fix your PHP.

```
$Json = array(
    array('test' => '1', 'message' => 'try it'), 
    array('test' => '2', 'message' => 'try it')
  );
$final = array(
  'error' => '1', 
  'json' => $Json
);
die(json_encode($final, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

You don't need to encode an already valid JSON string.

---

> All works fine

You never used `res` there. You printed the response body as-is.

```
Log.w("Return", response.body().toString());
```

This looks wrong. The response is already a JSON string, so `toJson` wouldn't be necessary.

```
jsonParser.parse(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
```

Your error is the "JsonPrimitive" in this case is a String, which is not a JSON object.

---

You should rather do this

```
final String body = response.body().toString(); // Or use response.raw(), if want raw response string
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject res = jsonParser.parse(body).getAsJsonObject();
Log.w("Return", res.toString());
```

If you want the data, then you can have

```
JsonArray data = res.getAsJsonArray("data");
```

---

Alternatively, you will need to make a POJO and deserialize your data list.

```
class Data {
    String test, message;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, when using your code i am getting this new error: `Not a JSON Object: "com.myapp.model.User@5a1a6fc"`

Comment: Well, a User isn't a JSONObject. My answer doesn't use a User class at all, so that is unrelated

Comment: My goal is to convert JSON to JsonArray and manipulate it, like getting the length() ... i can do that directly like this without changing my code: `JsonArray ress = res.get("JSON").getAsJsonArray();`, but getting the same error.

Comment: I believe you are looking for `gson.fromJson(jsonString, User.class)`, but that is listed in the Gson documentation, if you take a minute to find it and read though some examples

Comment: Are you using Retrofit, by chance? If so, you don't need to remap the JSON back through Gson to convert anything

Comment: Yes using Retrofit, return value of error is like this: `res.get("error").getAsString()` , for JSON i believe it will be like this: `res.get("message").getAsJsonArray()`, but return this error `This is not a JSON Array`..

Comment: I don't know what class you have used for the converter, but I assume it's `User` or `List<User>`? If not, why are you manually parsing the raw JSON?

Comment: I did that manually without requiring to use User class, User class is used for another activity.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, then, sorry. Feel free to edit the question with a [mcve]

Comment: Just one note, `.string()` of this line `final String body = response.body().string();` not recognized when i use your example.

Comment: If you are using Retrofit or OkHttp `public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response)`, it should be.

Comment: Yes `public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)`, there high probability that the problem come from the way PHP encoded the json no ? Must decode it first from Java and manipulate it then.

Comment: Actually, `response.raw()`, was what I wanted to put

Comment: Here how php show the Json result: `$final = [ 'error' => '1', 'json' => json_encode($Json)];`, when json_encode something, the json appear like this: ` [{\"test\":\"1\", \"message\":\"try it\"}, 
{\"test\":\"2\", \"message\":\"try it\"}, {\"test\":\"3\", \"message\":\"try it\"} ...]`

Comment: Your PHP is the issue, yes. Your `$Json` variable is a String, which doesn't need to be encoded. If you would like to encode something, you need an associative array like you made for `$final` and how you encoded that.

Comment: (Or you could use a different web server than PHP, if you aren't comfortable with it)

Comment: I encoded them well, you can check your self, the PHP code is in the POST, problem is how to decode it on Java.

Comment: No, you encoded an already valid JSON string to another JSON String. `"[{\"test\":\"1\"}]"` is not what Gson would like to parse. `[{"test":"1"}]` is

Comment: So, i displayed JSON data as string and the JSON is without al the `\"`, `res.get("JSON").getAsString()`, i think i will look for a solution to convert the String to a Json format.

Comment: This is your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739871/how-to-create-an-array-for-json-using-php

Comment: No is not this, you have to understand that my `MAIN JSON` containt two keys: `Error` and `Message`, `Error` is simple String that return 0 or 1, and `message` contain a Datas about another JSON that i will manipulate alone on Java side. For `Error` i can get it without error, but `message` is what we are debugging now.

Comment: Same result sir, when i show the json in a log with string format, it's a valid JSON format.

Comment: Not a JSON Object: "com.myapp.model.User@99d1185", JSON is decalred as String on user class, what is the right declaration to get it work ? will try to edit it.