# Convert byte[] to custom java object

Tags: java, arrays, json, byte

```
 private static MyClass doWork(byte[] body){        

    String data = new String(body);   
    Gson gson = new Gson();     
    final MyClass myClass = gson.fromJson(data, MyClass .class);  
    System.out.println("outsideLead"+myClass);
    return myClass;
}

byte[] body = {"N":"string","A":"string"}
```

When i try to convert my Byte[] to object of MyClass type, it throws me a error, that json object is expected instead a json primitive was found.
What is the correct way of doing it??

Comment: a json primitive was found? you're aware that Java doesn't have primitives of json type, right?

Comment: Expected a com.google.gson.JsonObject but was com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive - this is the error

Comment: Please post your `MyClass` class and update the question with that error.

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644376/com-google-gson-jsonprimitive-cannot-be-cast-to-com-google-gson-jsonobject

Comment: @Stultuske its gson error saying that myclass declares some field to be an object, but it is a value - number, or string eg

Comment: @Antoniossss which is clear after seeing the entire error message, not from the first one

Answer (score 1):

I guess your byte[] body doesn't contain the '{' and '}'. Try something like the following and it should work:

```
byte[] body = "{\"N\":\"string\",\"A\":\"string\"}".getBytes();
```

The error just says that instead of finding a JSON object (that always starts with a '{') - the parser got a primitive - I guess the string "N".

Comment: Thank you it works like a charm, but since my string in the program is dynamic i should write a regular expression to append escape character in front of double quotes, how do i do it

Comment: String data1 = new String(body1);   
data1 = data1.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");

Comment: I tried something like this and it throws me a error:om.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path

Comment: You dont need to use "\" in the String. It is required only when you use it literally in Java code.

Comment: While then it throws me the above error when i pass it dynamically

Comment: Just printout your string and see whether it is a valid JSON. May be you need to prepend and append '{' and '}' to your String. Easy way to check whether your String is a valid JSON or not is to just paste into a Browser console.