# Generate php array definition from JSON

Tags: php, json

My question is a bit different to most like this, I basically want to do the opposite to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435072/how-to-generate-json-using-php) from Haluk.
So I have a JSON string:

```
{
    "main":
    {
        "title": "QuickPub",
        "defaultRole": "BU"
    },
    "roles":
    {
        "TU":
        {
            "name": "testUser",
            "code": "TU"
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to be able to generate a string containing a php array definition from it:

```
<?php

return [
    "main" =>
    [
        "title" => "QuickPub",
        "defaultRole" => "BU"
    ],
    "roles" =>
    [
        "TU" =>
        [
            "name" => "testUser",
            "code" => "TU"
        ]
    ]
];

?>
```

EDIT:
I have tried `json_decode()` but this produces a variable, I need a string that I can put in a php file that will reproduce this without using php_decode.

Comment: Have you checked the PHP documentation? There is a built-in function that does exactly what you want. I will leave it to you as an exercise how to find it for yourself.

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted my question, I know of json_decode(), but I want to do the opposite, go from json to php

Comment: `json_decode()` _does_ go from JSON to PHP. Please edit your question to show the code you have so far and why it doesn't produce the results you want.

Comment: I have edited the question, does this help?

Comment: nevermind, I found a solution, I will post it as an answer

Comment: OK. So what you want is different from the question. You want to hard-code the same data in the JSON string as PHP, yes?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an adaptation of Being Sunny's answer, but using the `var_export()` function rather than print_r.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039431/difference-between-var-dump-var-export-print-r) by phihad

> var_export prints valid php code. Useful if you calculated some values and want the results as a constant in another script

the script:

```
$json   = '{"main":{"title": "QuickPub","defaultRole": "BU"},"roles":{"TU":{"name": "testUser","code": "TU"}}}';
$array  = json_decode($json, 1);
$result = var_export($array, 1);
echo $result;
```

produces:

```
array(
    'main'  => array(
        'title'       => 'QuickPub',
        'defaultRole' => 'BU',
    ),
    'roles' => array(
        'TU' => array(
            'name' => 'testUser',
            'code' => 'TU',
        ),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem. First of all convert your json string to an array using json_decode($string,1);  then convert that array to string representation using print_r($array,1); this will return your result as array string representation.

For example:

```
 $json='{}' // its a demo
 $array= json_decode($json,1); // an array
 $result = print_r($array,1);
 echo $result;
```

Comment: this would return `(
    [main] => array
    (
        [title] => QuickPub
        [defaultRole] => BU
    ),
    [roles] =>
    (
        [TU] =>
        (
            [name] => testUser
            [code] => TU
        )
    )
)` which is not valid php

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved using this code:

```
$output = 'return ' . rtrim(preg_replace(['/{/', '/}/', '/:/'], ['[', ']', ' =>'], $json)) . ';';
```

this replaces `{` with `[`, `}` with `]`, and `:` with `=>`, trims any whitespace from the end, appends a `;` and prepends a return statement.

this produces the output requested in the question bar the open and closing php tags.

Comment: There is a built-in to echo PHP variables as PHP-compatible strings. I suggest you look for that, rather than building your own solution.

Comment: This is going to fail very hard as soon as any of your property names or values contain any of those characters.

Comment: I realise that now, but I'll leave it as an option